# SDL Content Porter SP2 unable to save Page Template

Tags: cme, content-porter-2009

Using SDL Content Porter SP2, I have exported package successfully but while doing importing I am getting following error. Could you please help.

```
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040000" Category="18" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="false" MessageID="16137">
    <![CDATA[Unable to save Page Template (tcm:11-708-128).]]> 
    <tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_4445</tcm:Token> 
    <tcm:Token>tcm:11-708-128</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="true">
    <![CDATA[The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL.
```

Comment: Are you running the export using a single transaction? it seems that a transaction is timeout. Try disabling running in the same transaction.

Comment: Welcome, Rita, to Tridion Stack Exchange! We just saw another new member Rita recently join. Are you the same "Rita?" :-)

Comment: Hi Eric, I have restarted all the Tridion services and CM & DB servers , after that I have started the content porter to import the package still I am getting the same error.Package contains approx 350 items. Is there any thing that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Hi  Rita  Could you try importing  step by step,  dependencies of that PT  first, like any parameter schema, category keyword,  then metadata if any, tbbs and then the template itself.  It may be painful but will be helpful knowing the cause.